# SipJS and Freeswtch : Not able to receive phone call

Tags: sip, sipjs

Trying to call using **Freeswitch** and **sipJS based SipPhone**
   I am using **linphone** at one end and **sipjs** at another , lin phone is able to call browser bases sipJs phone as its ringing but I am not able to receive call
Here Are My Logs, Unauthorized UA Seems to be a problem

Logs :

```
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/WS hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8046067;received=100.74.156.116;rport=49654
From: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=ab7a6dqv0k
To: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=rS92SD9Zt6yDg
Call-ID: 52aucsstdsah4mf5499e6m
CSeq: 81 REGISTER
**User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b~64bit**
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: timer, path, replaces
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="100.74.156.116", nonce="f92c8e20-1906-4a61-b341-f6fd43e1be87", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
Content-Length: 0



sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

REGISTER sip:100.74.156.116 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK521909
Max-Forwards: 70
To: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>
From: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=ab7a6dqv0k
Call-ID: 52aucsstdsah4mf5499e6m
CSeq: 82 REGISTER
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="1000", realm="100.74.156.116", nonce="f92c8e20-1906-4a61-b341-f6fd43e1be87", uri="sip:100.74.156.116", response="357518a5593937845bf92f2e961f3b4c", qop=auth, cnonce="otm5sa1unt17", nc=00000001
Contact: <sip:c0e2i9qn@hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;transport=ws>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:e7733a3b-3480-48e6-a065-5af261036403>";expires=130
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: path, gruu, outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.3
Content-Length: 0



sip.js:2884 Fri Apr 15 2016 16:56:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WS hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK521909;received=100.74.156.116;rport=49654
From: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=ab7a6dqv0k
To: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=S22UU8S3QFN0B
Call-ID: 52aucsstdsah4mf5499e6m
CSeq: 82 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:c0e2i9qn@hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;transport=ws>;expires=130
Date: Fri, 15 Apr 2016 11:26:42 GMT
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: timer, path, replaces
Content-Length: 0

 sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

NOTIFY sip:c0e2i9qn@hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;transport=ws SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 100.74.156.116:5066;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmmBevgH597eDF
Route: <sip:c0e2i9qn@100.74.156.116:49654>;transport=ws
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=tBvmX3a7mrBKQ
To: <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>
Call-ID: c51139ce-7d9f-1234-0faa-37dc5feb612c
CSeq: 90023737 NOTIFY
Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@100.74.156.116:5060>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: timer, path, replaces
Event: message-summary
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
Subscription-State: terminated;reason=noresource
Content-Type: application/simple-message-summary
Content-Length: 66

Messages-Waiting: no
Message-Account: sip:1000@100.74.156.116


sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

SIP/2.0 405 Method Not Allowed
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 100.74.156.116:5066;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmmBevgH597eDF
To: <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=ao6rh9rc8h
From: <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=tBvmX3a7mrBKQ
Call-ID: c51139ce-7d9f-1234-0faa-37dc5feb612c
CSeq: 90023737 NOTIFY
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.3
Content-Length: 0



REGISTER sip:100.74.156.116 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9236948
Max-Forwards: 70
To: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>
From: "1000" <sip:1000@100.74.156.116>;tag=ab7a6dqv0k
Call-ID: 52aucsstdsah4mf5499e6m
CSeq: 83 REGISTER
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="1000", realm="100.74.156.116", nonce="f92c8e20-1906-4a61-b341-f6fd43e1be87", uri="sip:100.74.156.116", response="357518a5593937845bf92f2e961f3b4c", qop=auth, cnonce="otm5sa1unt17", nc=00000001
Contact: <sip:c0e2i9qn@hntgukqjg2hc.invalid;transport=ws>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:e7733a3b-3480-48e6-a065-5af261036403>";expires=130
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,INVITE,MESSAGE,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: path, gruu, outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.3
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

above is just registration logs and its registered fine with 200 OK.

Comment: Its workin :) ,  i have another problem though , calling is working fine,but         ' call on hold  '  isn't, call gets disconected immidiately without any error logs . (sipjs)

Comment: are you calling .hold() function in sipjs? What's the SIP response you getting on call disconnect?